# Is there a mozilla equivalent to webkitGetAsEntry?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Now that webkitGetAsEntry() has been activated on Chrome 21 to allow folder drag&drop, is there an equivalent in mozilla - mozGetAsEntry(), getAsEntry(), or something else?  I've only been able to find very minimal info on webkit's method and the whatwg proposal; I can find nothing for Firefox (or any other browsers).

References:

- http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/DragAndDropEntries#DataTransferItem.getAsEntry.28.29

  http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available

  http://blog.protonet.info/post/26894439416/html5-drag-drop-files-and-folders

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `mozGetDataAt()` method, which returns an `nsIFile` object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#file

So to answer your question, the equivalent would be:

`mozEntry = event.dataTransfer.mozGetDataAt(0);`

or..

`event.dataTransfer.mozGetDataAt(0).isFile()` etc.

Documentation for `nsIFile`(contains the fields that are in the webkit entries):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile

Comment: So far as I can tell, that Firefox capability is roughly equivalent to Chrome's webkitdirectory attribute in that it only works on inputs of type file.  webkitGetAsEntry instead works on just about anything (if I could only get it to work right...), such as a div.

Comment: _"Non-privileged web pages are not able to retrieve or modify data of this type."_ [MDN Guide to dragging files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types#Dragging_Files). `mozGetDataAt` call results in "Permission denied" error.